# Does Mulesoft JQL-Search connector support Auto Pagination?

Tags: pagination, mule, jql

Does Mulesoft JQL-Search connector support Auto Pagination, as I am not able to get the pagination attributes such as  "maxResults","total","startAt".
I can only see Page Size attribute in the JQL-Search Mule connector , does it doing auto pagination internally ?

Comment: To what connector are you referring to exactly? Please provide the URL for documentation or in Anypoint Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

There is no MuleSoft JQL search connector. The [MuleSoft JIRA connector](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/com.mulesoft.connectors/mule4-jira-connector/) has an [Evaluate JIRA expression](https://docs.mulesoft.com/jira-connector/1.0/jira-connector-reference#CreateRestApi3ExpressionEval) **operation** but it doesn't mention any paging.